# How to write a unit test in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, laravel, laravel-4

I'm writing a simple library I can reuse in some of my projects. At the moment its just going to swap some 'dumb' characters for their smart equivalent. Anyway, I installed a fresh instance of laravel 4 then ran `php artisan workbench jonnybarnes/dumbquotes`. Then I wrote some code in `DumbquotesParser.php`. This currently resides `LARAVEL/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/src/Jonnybarnes/Dumbquotes/DumbquotesParser.php`. So I created a test file for this in the provided tests folder:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../src/Jonnybarnes/Dumbquotes/DumbquotesParser.php';

class DumbquotesParserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testApostrophe()
    {
        $actual = DumbquotesParser::apostrophe('We\'re testing Jonny\'s apotrophes\' form');
        $expected = 'We’re testing Jonny’s apostrophes’ form';

        $this->assertEquals($actual, $excpected);
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work. I'm not entirely sure how to get phpunit to load the parser. I get the following output:

```
jonny@jonny-arch:~/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes|testing ⇒  ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests
PHPUnit 3.7.21-2-g268d9f1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/phpunit.xml

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DumbquotesParser' not found in /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/tests/DumbquotesParserTest.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:63
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:776
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:831
PHP  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
PHP  13. DumbquotesParserTest->testApostrophe() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976

Fatal error: Class 'DumbquotesParser' not found in /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/tests/DumbquotesParserTest.php on line 8

Call Stack:
    0.0002     231432   1. {main}() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0036     609112   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:63
    0.0036     609344   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
    0.0220    2346712   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
    0.0474    2638864   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
    0.0476    2640512   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
    0.0477    2641112   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
    0.0477    2641144   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
    0.0478    2642352   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:776
    0.0510    2700216  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
    0.0515    2719488  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:831
    0.0515    2720768  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
    0.0515    2720800  13. DumbquotesParserTest->testApostrophe() /home/jonny/dumbquotes-bench/workbench/jonnybarnes/dumbquotes/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:976
```

So how can I get to actually load the parser?

Changing my test file to so makes the test work:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../src/Jonnybarnes/Dumbquotes/DumbquotesParser.php';


class DumbquotesParserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testApostrophe()
    {
        $parser = new \Jonnybarnes\Dumbquotes\DumbquotesParser();
        $actual = $parser->apostrophe('We\'re testing Jonny\'s apostrophes\' form');
        $expected = 'We’re testing Jonny’s apostrophes’ form';

        $this->assertEquals($actual, $expected);
    }
}
```

Do I need to put `$parser = new \...\...\...();` in every test?

Comment: Next time, simply add your own answer using the normal mechanism and don't alter the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can also import the namespaced class into the global namespace like this (right after the include):

```
use Jonnybarnes\Dumbquotes\DumbquotesParser;
```

You can then forget about the `setUp()` method (since you're just testing a static method here) and keep the actual test code that you originally posted:

```
$actual = DumbquotesParser::apostrophe('We\'re testing Jonny\'s apotrophes\' form');
```